# Permutations with No letters-digits repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A car license plate consists of 3 capital letters of the English alphabet in the first 3 positions of the license plate followed by 4 digits from 0 to 9.  How many different plates can we have if neither the same letter nor the same digit on the plate is allowed to be repeated?

I was wondering if the right answer is $26! \cdot 10!$, based on permutations?

I would appreciate for your guidance, as I face great difficulty in it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\frac{26!}{23!}$ ways to select the letter portion of the plate and $\frac{10!}{6!}$ ways to select the number portion.  The product is the total number of possible plates with these contraints.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. And if We were allowed to repeat the same letter and the same number as well, then there would be 26!*10! different ways?

Comment: @Magda No.  There would be $26^3 \cdot 10^4$ ways if letters and digits were allowed to repeat since you would have $26$ choices fro each of the three letters and $10$ choices for each of the four digits.

Comment: That is absolutely clear, Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Magda, please mark question answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have not taken the number of letters or digits into account.

Answer the following questions, keeping in mind that neither a letter nor a digit may be repeated.

1. In how many ways can the first position be filled with a letter?
2. Given that the first position has been filled with a letter, in how many ways can the second position be filled with a letter?
3. Given that the first two positions have been filled with letters, in how many ways can the third position be filled with a letter?
4. In how many ways can the fourth position be filled with a digit?
5. Given that the fourth position has been filled with a digit, in how many ways can the fifth position be filled with a digit?
6. Given that the fourth and fifth positions have been filled with digits, in how many ways can the sixth position be filled with a digit?
7. Given that the fourth, fifth, and sixth positions have been filled with digits, in how many ways can the seventh position be filled with a digit?

Use the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product:) to conclude.

> There are $26$ ways to fill the first position with a letter, $25$ ways to fill the second position with a different letter, $24$ ways to fill the third position with a letter that has not yet been used, $10$ ways to fill the fourth position with a digit, $9$ ways to fill the fifth position with a different digit, $8$ ways to fill the sixth position with a digit that has not yet been used, and $7$ ways to fill the seventh position with a digit that has not yet been used.  Hence, by the Multiplication Principle, there are $$26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$$ license plates in which the first three characters are distinct letters of the English alphabet and the last four characters are distinct decimal digits.